# Changing a child and grandchild git fork to a single child fork?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

We are currently using one `parent` git repository (which we do not control), and two forks. `fork1` is a fork of `parent`, and `fork2` is a fork of `fork1`.

```
parent
  |
  V
fork1
  |
  V
fork2
```

I periodically sync each fork using commands such as:

```bash
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

Our software is installed using files built by both `fork1` and `fork2` (headers and libraries).

Is it possible to do this using just one fork of the parent? `fork2` differs only in a few tens of files from `fork1`. Perhaps I could add these files within a new subdirectory within `fork1`, but I'm not sure if I would still use git commands to perform the "local" equivalent of the fork sync commands listed above. Would I use git's mergetool? Do any other projects face similar issues?

Comment: Presumably fork2 has a master that is somewhat different from fork1's master? Why not make that a branch on fork1, and merge from fork1/master into fork1/branch-in-lieu-of-fork2?

Comment: But yes, the extra files cold also exist in fork1/master, and when you merge upstream/master into fork1/master, that would preserve you extra files.

Comment: @joanis Thanks. Your first suggestion does sound good. My only thought here had been that there is somehow something irregular about switching branches midway through our build/install procedure. Perhaps that is not true?
     
For your second suggestion: I would then also need to periodically sync the "extra" files (originally from fork2). Do you have an idea which tool would be used to help with that? Presumably I would also have to maintain correlation between each "extra" source file with its "parent".

Comment: Personally, I would try to avoid switching branch during the build, do I'd go for my second suggestion. And then I would maintain those files by committing their changes directly into fork1/master. When you merge from upstream, it should keep combining things correctly. Over time you'll end up with a lot of merge commits, but I think that's fine, as long as you never need to merge back to upstream.

Comment: But when I merge from the upstream parent, the "extra" files will not be updated. Perhaps there is a particular way to add these files? I assume in this approach, only fork1/master is required.

Comment: Yeah, I would say if you're willing to have your extra files live on fork1/master, then it's the only branch you need.

Comment: When you merge from the upstream, the files that are maintained there will get updated, while the extra files will remain as they were before the merge. If you need to update the extra file, do some commits on your fork1/master to update them.

Answer (score 1):

##### General approach

This is the approach I would use, based on the conversation in the comments:

Use just one fork, and add the extra files in a directory in your fork's master branch. When you merge from upstream, that will bring in the changes made there. When you need changes to the extras, do them in your fork.

##### Setup

Let's say the extras all live in a directory called `extras`.

I'm assuming you have a sandbox that was cloned from your fork, or `origin` is your fork, and has `upstream` as its second remote pointing to the upstream of your fork.

```
git clone URL_of_my_fork/repo
cd repo
git remote add upstream URL_of_upstream/repo
```

##### Preparing fork/master with the extras

```
# create the files in `extras/`
git add extras
git commit  # assuming you're already on master here
git push origin  # push to fork/master
```

##### Getting updates from upstream

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push origin
```

##### Applying changes required to the extras

```
# edit extras/* as needed
git add extras
git commit
git push origin
```

##### Continuing

Rinse and repeat!

Each time you need to get an update from upstream, merge again from `upstream/master` like above.

Each time you need to modify the extra files, do so and commit again like above.

##### Simulated results

I've created a simulated repo following the procedure above. After two merges from upstream and two sets of changes to the extras, my history looks like this:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate
* ed44112 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) another update of the extras
*   b29d198 Merge branch 'upstream/master' into master
|\
| * c6e4e24 (upstream/master) more changes made on upstream
* | 57a24ad updating the extra files
* | 19de09c Merge branch 'upstream/master' into master
|\|
| * ace26ef change made on upstream
* | 84213f7 adding extra files
|/
* ea660ea upstream commit 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I still wonder how the extra files can be updated from changes upstream. Let's say we have files A and B in the upstream repo. The fork then also has its version of A and B. These are updated either from an upstream sync, or by edits in the fork. The `extras` folder might also have copies of A and B, which are further variations of the A and B of the fork. When I sync the fork from upstream, how do I get the changes to the fork's A and B files, applied to the A and B files in `extras`?